# Does EMI shielding deteriorate with time?

Tags: voltage, resistance, electromagnetism, emc, shielding

Does EMI shielding sheets gain resistance/impedance with time?

I am using a ~2 year old RF EMI Absorb sheet that my roommate found and gave to me because my electronics keep interfering with his radio. I use the sheet to prevent the EMI from his radio affecting my motors inside a container.

As I was checking the circuit for continuity I noticed that this sheet does not conduct electricity - it has a ~20 kΩ resistance - and if I know anything about circuits it's that if I put shielding over a box and ground it then no more EMI.

The shielding is either silicone rubber or silicone elastomer material, it looks very similar to electrical tape but it's not it because the resistance of the electric tape is 0L MΩ and for this its 20 kΩ.
I can easily use another shielding but I'm curious how this could've happened.

Comment: Page 4 of this datasheet may make it clearer (https://content.kemet.com/datasheets/KEM_FS8001_EF.pdf) but that material is likely designed to absorb radio waves, rather than act as a faraday cage (which sort of conducts radio waves around your container, preventing them from affecting what's inside it). It has probably always had 20k of resistance, and you probably dont have to ground it (although it might not hurt)

Comment: What made you suspect it had deteriorated in the first place?

Comment: @winny I did not consider the existence of RF only sheets )))

Comment: Before your DC measurement.

Comment: I thought it was so because it was old

Comment: Datasheet from the manufacturer should be your first resource here. Electrolytic capacitors wear, lasers wear and LEDs fade. Apart from that, most stuff used in the electronic industry tend to be stable over time.

Answer (score 1):

Our antenna ranges use RF absorber all over the place - the way most consumers use toilet paper.  I am not aware of a wear-out or deterioration mechanism that would require the absorber be replaced.

Sometimes absorber has to be replaced if it gets damaged, like from a water leak or burned from a focused high power radar beam (seen that happen).

Other times it may be replaced if it's absorption characteristics don't match what's needed for the system in the range, such as a big change in the operating frequency.

But I've never seen absorber replaced just based on elapsed time.

Answer (score 0):

A perfectly conductive sheet does *not* absorb radio waves. It reflects them. Since you have an *absorber*, you shouldn't expect it to conduct very well. So, what you observe is what is expected.

Whether some deterioration has happened is a separate matter, but you can't tell it from a measurement with an ohm meter. You'd need to do RF measurements. So the presumption that something has deteriorated is not grounded in any results yet.

Most likely, you have nothing to worry about, unless you've been mechanically, chemically or physcially abusing the sheet.